# managed dll from c#, no error, but nothing happens

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop

I have created a dll in C++ (windows 10, 64 bit dll, release configuration)

I have only one function in it.

```
extern "C"
{

    __declspec(dllexport) void ConnectX()
    {

        std::cout << "yes" << std::endl;

    }

}
```

When I create a new c# project, and call a function from this using:

```
 [DllImport("XsensGrab.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void ConnectX();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread threadConnect = new Thread(ConnectX);
            threadConnect.Start();
        }
```

it works as expected.

When i add this same code to the existing project that i created it for, and run it, nothing happens. no error, but no connection either.

Both C# projects are release/ANY_CPU.

I cannot see a difference. Why would this work in one project, but not another? What setting in the C# application can I check to find the cause?

Comment: Hard for us to tell where the problem could be, we don't even know the declaration for the C++ function. Could you check the return value of `ConnectX`, and also make sure there's no exception listed in the Immediate Window?

Comment: ..added the c++ function.

Comment: Try debugging dll. Set it up so that on debug it starts your exe, set a breakpoint at the start of the function, and hit F5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean switch the output type to exe instead of dll?

Comment: Why does the C++ implementation not have a calling convention?

Comment: Hi, I am new to this dll stuff really. Did I miss something?

Comment: In C# you've set the P/Invoke calling convention to `Cdecl`, but you haven't specified it in the C++ dll. Try adding `__cdecl` to your C++ function declaration: `__declspec(dllexport) __cdecl void ConnectX()`.

Comment: I have added the output from the output window. `module was built without symbols`. What does this mean?

Comment: adding that line gives me `type void unexpected` EDIT, switching to `__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl ConnectX()` compiles. But i see the same result when i run it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I put it in the wrong place. this is the correct: `__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl ConnectX()`. -- The thing you got from the output window just indicates that the dll was compiled/built without debugging symbols. This doesn't matter though.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to a computer, so I'm not able to test your code at the moment...

Comment: The weird thing is, it runs fine in a new c# project. But not in the existing one.

Comment: This should be obvious, but since you are writing to the console the process must have allocated a console (either explicitly, or by targeting /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE, and have the OS allocate one for it) to see any console output. Is this the case for your existing project?

Comment: this would mean it would not work in any c# app though, correct? It runs in one, but not another.

Answer (score -1):

What I needed was to change the build settings / Platform target from ANY CPU, to x86, and the dll to win32.

Comment: Why the downvote? I asked a question, then answered it